# How to express not within/inside predicate in spatial database with good performance

Tags: sql, spatial-database

In our application we want to express some spatial predicates as objects not within some areas, but unfortunately it has very bad performance. The following SQL is generated by our application:

```
SELECT *
FROM geom_table
WHERE NOT (SDO_INSIDE(geom_column, SDO_GEOMETRY(...), srid) = 'True'
AND geom_column IS NOT NULL);
```

I've been searching on internet for a while but surprisingly fail to find any information talking about it. I think it's not a non-reality use case, or is it? I wonder if there is a better way to express the SQL statement?

Comment: "not inside" or "not intersects" queries are generally poor performers in any system because they can't leverage spatial indexes